# Show progress in python program while calling external time consuming function

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar

I have a python program which solves a large integer programming problem. I use Pyomo to model and Gurobi for solving. I have silenced gurobi, as it is rather chatty and pollutes the terminal output a bit. However, I would still like to show the user, that stuff is going on. How do you do that? All the progress-bar applications I have found obviously needs a "end time"/last iteration to function. I don't need a fancy progress bar. Just something that shows that program is still runing.

To illustrate my needs I have something like the following

```
print('Reading data')
readDataQuickly(...)
print('Data read. Now model will be created')
createModelQuickly(...)
print('Model created. Now solving starts')
veryTimeConsumingFunctionIDontControl(...) # <- Show stuff is going on here
print('Thanks for your patience')
```

I am using Python 3.10 if it matters

I have tried different kinds of process bars which works great, if I am the one who implemented the time consuming part, as I can add the progress indicator in e.g. loops. However, here I do not have access to the code of the solver, and hence, I cannot show progress from "outside".

Answer (score 0):

[[image: You can use this package - tqdm]

Very simple to use this, you need to integrate inside your function to show the progress bar.

Comment: Yes, this is extremely easy to use, when I implement my own loop, because then tqdm can show the percentage progress and what not. But here I do not know how much time/iterations/work needs to be done by the `veryTimeConsumingFunctionIDontControl(...)`. Hence, I do not really need a progress bar. I just need something that can show that stuff is going on even though the solver doesn't print a lot of stuff to the prompt.